# How get message text sent by my bot using message ID in telegraf-nodejs?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegraf.js

I've built a bot that send messages in a channel by nodejs using telegraf; I save the message ID returned by the 'sendmessage' function because I need to add addictional text to it after a while.

I've seen that there is the function 'editMessageText' for change the text, but how can I read the text previusly sent to avoid to store the text too?
Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.